# Access token API Graph Facebook

Tags: facebook, angular, typescript, facebook-graph-api

I use Angular 2 and 4 in order to show Facebook events and attending on my website.

```
if(link.match('^http://www.facebook.com/|https://www.facebook.com/')){
        console.log("Facebook link")
        id = link.split('https://www.facebook.com/')[1].split('?')[0]; 
        fblink = this.http.get(`https://graph.facebook.com/${id}?fields=events.limit(1000){id,name,description,cover,start_time,end_time,attending_count,place,photos{source},attending{first_name,last_name,cover}}&access_token=MYACCESSTOKEN`)      
        .map(events => events.json().events.data);
    }
```

This example works because I use the id of a Facebook page. But when I want to use the search option the access token doesn't works.

```
fblink = this.http.get(`https://graph.facebook.com/v2.9/search?q=${id}&fields=id,name,place,cover,attending_count,start_time,description&type=event&access_token=MYACCESSTOKEN`)      
         .map(events => events.json().data);
```

But when I put the access token from the Facebook API Graph tool it works and this token stay about 1 hour and I have to retake the access token from the API Graph tool.

Is there a solution? I don't use any SDK from Facebook maybe there is a solution.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: You need to use a user access token to search for events, that is not possible using the app access token. And since the search results are tailored to the requesting user, it would make most sense if you simply integrated Facebook login to your app, so that the users can login to it, and you can then use their user access token to perform the search.

Comment: you got a refresh token too, if exprired -> refresh token to have a new token, then you can do your request